# OrientDB Edges don't show rid

Tags: node.js, graph-databases, orientjs

I am creating vertices and connecting vertices with edges.

For example, I make a vertex (`95:0`) in the class `book` and connect this vertex to a certain "user" (`50:0`) in the class `user` via an edge called `ownedByUser` going IN the `user` class . Sometimes these edges and vertices are updated using the transaction builder mentioned in the OrientJS manual :=  [transaction manual - orientjs](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/OrientJS-Transactions.html)

If I query the above in the `user` class, I should ideally get the below response:

```
{
  "@type": "d",
  "@rid": "#50:0",
  "@version": 76,
  "@class": "User",
  "in_ownedByUser": [
    "#277:28"
  ],
  "createdDate": "2017-03-21 10:55:20",
  "isPicAvailable": false,
  "email": "xyz@xyz.com",
  "organization": "SOME_ORG",
  "uname": "cool_user",
  "confirm_password": "welcome",
  "tnc": true,
  "id": "50:0",
  "activeFlag": true,
  "@fieldTypes": "in_ownedByUser=g,createdDate=t"
}
```

where `"in_ownedByUser": [
        "#277:28"
      ],` is the edge rid of the edge between the book(`95:0`) and the user (`50:0`).

But sometimes the query returns as the below:

```
{
  "@type": "d",
  "@rid": "#50:0",
  "@version": 31,
  "@class": "User",
  "createdDate": "2017-04-05 12:35:24",
  "isPicAvailable": true,
  "activeFlag": true,
  "email": "xyz@xyz.com",
  "organization": "SOME+ORG",
  "uname": "cool_user",
  "confirm_password": "welcome",
  "tnc": true,
  "in_ownedByUser": [
    {
      "@type": "d",
      "@version": 0,
      "@class": "ownedByUser",
      "out": "#94:58",
      "in": "#48:23",
      "@fieldTypes": "out=x,in=x"
    }
  ],
  "id": "50:0",
  "@fieldTypes": "in_ownedByUser=g,createdDate=t"
}
```

Notice that the key `in_ownedByUser` has the document directly and not the edge rid. This document inside `in_ownedByUser` is also missing an rid. an anyone tell me what is happening here? This doesn't happen all the time. I would like to know in what scenario does the edge rid get replaced with this document tppe of value.